# audio tag in html is not working

Tags: html

I have made this html but it is not working. The players are not showing up.

```
<audio id="music">
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1/file1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio id="music">
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1/file2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure you have multiple file types for each audio file, because different browsers support different file types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had your problem lately and after some time Ive found that you should add `controls` attribute in `<audio>` elements to make them showing up. (also i changed ids, two items should not have same id)

```
<audio controls id="music1">
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1/file1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio controls id="music2">
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1/file2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```